# Shopify - prepopulate billing address based on query param

Tags: shopify, url-parameters, query-string, shopify-api

I am trying to prepopulate the shipping/billing address in Shopify checkout via URL query params. I've found this is easy to do with the shipping address as referenced here:

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Autofill-checkout-fields/td-p/318793

But when I try to do the same with the billing info, the "Same as shipping address" radio is always selected on the payment screen and if I manually select the option for a different address, all values are blank

How can I prepopulate both addresses? I've tried adding the billing query params directly to the checkout payment page URL, but that does not work either. Here is the URL I've been trying:

```
demo-store.myshopify.com/checkout?checkout[email]=fake.name@gmail.com&checkout[shipping_address][first_name]=John&checkout[shipping_address][last_name]=Doe&checkout[shipping_address][address1]=333%20Fake%20St.&checkout[shipping_address][city]=San%20Diego&checkout[shipping_address][province]=CA&checkout[shipping_address][country]=USA&checkout[shipping_address][zip]=92116&checkout[shipping_address][phone]=333-333-3333&checkout[different_billing_address]=true&checkout[billing_address][first_name]=Jane&checkout[billing_address][last_name]=Doe&checkout[billing_address][address1]=444%20Fake%20St%20&checkout[billing_address][city]=San%20Diego&checkout[billing_address][province]=CA&checkout[billing_address][country]=USA&checkout[billing_address][zip]=92121&checkout[billing_address][phone]=444-444-4444
```

Also, bonus question, the shipping state always seems to be populated based on IP address, so even if I pass it a value, it shows the state I'm in. How can I get it to always reflect the value of the query param?

Comment: Did you manage to prepopulate Contact information based on query param

Answer (score 2):

To create a prepopulated checkout on Shopify, you will need to supply the checkout through either the [Admin API](https://shopify.dev/apps/channels/checkout-api) or the [Storefront API](https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/checkout)

To create a checkout and return the web URL, send a POST request to the admin/checkouts.json endpoint.

Depending on how you choose to do this it can be achieved with many different points of access, as referenced in the [Shopify Dev portal](https://shopify.dev/), though you will not be able to complete this in the requested manner using only URL parameters.

For further reading, please refer to the [Getting started for the Storefront API](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/getting-started) and the [Storefront API Checkout Object](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/reference/checkouts/checkout)

Comment: The storefront API only allows to set the shipping address, there's no direct way to set the billing address in either a cart or a checkout resource.